# Document Database - Query by Interface property implementation type

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb, document-database

In our app we have a Ship object and a ship can be assigned Jobs. Each Job has a WorkRole that describes the work the Ship is doing.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Job
{
    public string ShipId { get; set; }
    public IWorkRole WorkRole { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Start { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset End{ get; set; }
}

public class Ship
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IWorkRole
{
    string Comments { get; set; }
}

public class RigMoveWorkRole : IWorkRole
{
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string RigId { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

There can be many different types of WorkRole each with different properties.

I would like to be able to query a Ships Jobs by its WorkRole. So for example query all Jobs for a Ship that did a RigMoveWorkRole.

Is this approach a good way to model this as im not sure if querying by an Objects type is a good solution, although it can be done with RavenDB. I thought about embedding an Enum in each WorkRole so i could easily query using that, for example:

```
public interface IWorkRole
{
    WorkRoleType WorkRoleType { get; }
    string Comments { get; }
}

public abstract class WorkRoleBase : IWorkRole
{
    public WorkRoleType WorkRoleType { get; private set; }
    public string Comments { get; protected set; }

    protected WorkRoleBase(WorkRoleType type)
    {
        WorkRoleType = type;
    }
}

public class AllDutiesWorkRole : WorkRoleBase
{
    public AllDutiesWorkRole(string comments) : base(WorkRoleType.AllDuties)
    {
        Comments = comments;
    }
}

public class RigMoveWokRole : WorkRoleBase
{
    public string RigId { get; private set; }

    public RigMoveWokRole(string rigId, string comments) : base(WorkRoleType.RigMove)
    {
        RigId = rigId;
        Comments = comments;
    }
}

public enum WorkRoleType
{
    RigMove,
    AllDuties
}
```

This way i could just query the IWorkRole.WorkRoleType interface property on the Job class:

```
Session.Query<Job>().Where(x => x.WorkRole.WorkRoleType == WorkRoleType.RigMove);
```

Can anyone see any problems with this model or have any suggestions for a better way to do it ?

Thanks !